What evidence is there that Hecate's speech in Act IV, Scene 1 of Macbeth was added in later?
In Act IV, Scene 1 of Macbeth, the famous "Double, double toil and trouble" scene, Hecate shows up for a brief moment to comment on the brewing:

Enter Hecate to the other three Witches.
Hecate
O, well done! I commend your pains;
And every one shall share i' the gains:
And now about the cauldron sing,
Like elves and fairies in a ring,
Enchanting all that you put in.
[Music and a song: "Black spirits," &c.
[Hecate retires.
Macbeth, Act IV, Scene 1, Amsco Literature Program edition

In the notes in this edition, they state:

Hecate's speech is thought to have been interpolated, not part of the original play.

However, no further information on this is presented.
Why is this speech thought to have been added in and not part of the original play? What about this section is different from the rest of the text? What evidence is there for this theory?
